# .ion-slide width less than device width causing space after last slide

Tags: javascript, slideshow, ionic3, ion-slides

I am using ionic latest version. Using ion-slide, I have limited the width of every single slide to 80% which is working fine.
But if we scroll it to the end, there is white space area left and all the slides hide to the left.

Snapshot : https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/notpol-staging.appspot.com/o/share.PNG?alt=media&token=12d91447-5a34-499f-b7af-b587acdd6b1b

```
<ion-slides style="height: 34%" speed="2000">
    <ion-slide style="width:80%">
      <ion-card>
        <img src="./assets/images/slider4.jpg" />
        <ion-card-content>
          <ion-card-title>
            Hair Style
          </ion-card-title>
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide style="width:80%">
        <ion-card>
          <img src="./assets/images/slider4.jpg" />
          <ion-card-content>
            <ion-card-title>
              Hair Style
            </ion-card-title>
          </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-slide>
      <ion-slide style="width:80%">
          <ion-card>
            <img src="./assets/images/slider4.jpg" />
            <ion-card-content>
              <ion-card-title>
                Hair Style
              </ion-card-title>
            </ion-card-content>
          </ion-card>
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide style="width:80%">
            <ion-card>
              <img src="./assets/images/slider4.jpg" />
              <ion-card-content>
                <ion-card-title>
                  Hair Style
                </ion-card-title>
              </ion-card-content>
            </ion-card>
          </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
```

Comment: There is white space left because you have given `height:34%`

Comment: No, height is just limiting area vertically. While I am talking about white space left after last slide horizontally beacuase of 80% width

Comment: OK. I guess I misunderstood from the description. Sorry. Maybe a screenshot could help describe it clearly

Comment: I have attached snapshot link inside the post, check it out